# Combine Two Unrelated Tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've never had to do this, and it's just for the purpose of displaying information on a gridview control in asp.net.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT [VisitNumber], [Date], [DateFreq], [Weight], [Fat], [BloodPressure], [Pulse], [Total], [Discount], [NetTotal], [AmountPaid], [PaymentStatus], [TypeOfPayment], [Comments] FROM [tblVisits] WHERE ([PatientID] = '16') 

SELECT [DatePrescribed], [AdditionalSupply], [Medication], [Dose], [Quantity], [Type], [Description], [Expires], [Lot] FROM [tblMedications] WHERE (([PatientID] = '16') AND ([DatePrescribed] = (select top 1 dateprescribed from tblMedications where ([PatientID] = '16') order by DatePrescribed desc))) ORDER BY [DatePrescribed] DESC
```

Is there any way to combine them, maybe a full join on PatientID? I'm not very good with sql, so any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "combine"? What you expect for output or a sample output might be enough to clarify.

Comment: All I want to do is display every column of both of those queries into one gridview.

Comment: Assuming a patient can have multiple visits and multiple medications, you can't combine both those queries into one result set based on patient ID. If you join on patient ID only you will end up with duplicate rows. If there is a way to associate individual visits with medications, then you need to use that as well, otherwise you will have to have separate result sets for each query.

Comment: @jpmc26, I'd like to display every patient visit, and each medication prescribed on the same date to the same patient.

Comment: Sorry. Been deleting my comments as my understanding changes. So do you expect to have many medication rows with many different dates? Your current query seems to limit the medication to the most recent date. You're not trying to match up medications with visits based on date, are you?

Comment: yeah I was, I forgot to change that, I took it from the form that only limits medication by the most recent date.

Comment: Also, I feel like an idiot since you actually said you were trying to match them based on date. Sorry for being dense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, you're trying to join the medications to the visits based on what medication was prescribed on the day of the visit. In that case, you need to join on that information:

```
SELECT [tblVisits].[VisitNumber], [tblVisits].[Date], ..., [tblVisits].[Comments],
       [tblMedications].[DatePrescribed], ..., [tblMedications].[Expires], [tblMedications].[Lot]
FROM [tblVisits]
JOIN [tblMedications] ON [tblVisits].[PatientID] = [tblMedications].[PatientID]
                     AND [tblVisits].[Date] = [tblMedications].[DatePrescribed]
WHERE [tblVisits].[PatientID] = '16'
ORDER BY [tblVisits].[Date]
```

I would like to mention that I think saying that these two tables are "unrelated" isn't the best way to put it. They do have a meaningful relationship for your application based on the dates; it's just not explicit in the form of a foreign key because it's not a key based relationship.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want some sort of SQL join by `patientID`.

- If you want to include only records with IDs that were in both tables, use `inner join`.
- If you want all of the records, with `null`s where an ID was in one table but not the other, use `full outer join`.
- If you want all the records from one table, with `null`s where the other table didn't have that ID, use `left` or `right outer join`.

It seems most likely that you'll want an `inner join`, something like this:

```
select v.VisitNumber, v.Date, ..., v.Comments, m.DatePrescribed, m.AdditionalSupply...
from tblVisits as v inner join tblMedication as m
on v.PatientID = m.PatientID;
```

[Source](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)